# TypeScript: filtering in mapped types

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a mapped type, where the mapping would depend on the type of a property. For instance, assume that I want to map all `String` properties to a type `Foo` and all other to `Bar`. So, I'd like to do something like:

```
type Mapped<T> = {
   [P in keyof T]: T[P] === String ? Foo : Bar
}
```

Is there any syntax to achieve this?

Comment: If you need some of the keys to be completely filtered out see this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23199

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to install `typescript@next` or wait for version 2.8 to be officially released.

You can then achieve what you want like this:

```
type Mapped<T> = {
   [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? Foo : Bar
}
```